# C# SharePoint get entire folder path my item is in

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I know I can get the current folder the document is in but I need to get all of the folders up to the library level.

Document Library
**Folder1
****Folder2
******Folder3
*******Document

When I use properties.ListItem.File.ParentFolder.Name; on the "Document", it just gives me "Folder 3"  What I'd like to eventually get is "Document Library\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3"

**Thanks Cory,**
I used your method and this is how I did it.  I'd upvote but I don't have enough points...

`string currentItemName = properties.ListItem.Name;
string currentItemPath = properties.ListItem.Url;
currentItemPath= currentItemPath.Replace(currentItemName, "");`

Comment: Is this client object model/server object model, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this by capturing the relative URL of the file, which is just `properties.ListItem.Url` in your case. This might give you something like:

> /Document Packages/Folder ABC/Document XYZ.doc

Then you can trim off everything after the last `/`.

Answer (score 0):

We can start out creating a generic function to, when given a node in a tree, return a sequence of that node and all of its ancestors:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAncestors<T>(
    this T node,
    Func<T, T> parentSelector)
{
    while (node != null)
    {
        yield return node;
        node = parentSelector(node);
    }
}
```

It's then as simple as passing the item's folder into this method along with a simple lambda to get that folder's parent:

```
var folder = item.Folder;
var allFolders = GetAncestors(folder, f => f.ParentFolder);
```